# Rails using ActiveRecord "where" when parameter takes an Array

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to use a rails "where" query using activeRecord. The query i have contains multiple conditions, one of which is an array:

```
User.where("state = ? AND salary >= ?", ["AL", "MI", "MA"], 1000)
```

The problem is that when I run it (either from a controller, or from a console), I don't get any errors, but what looks like an empty ActiveRecord object. If I have just one value in the array, it works fine. Its multiple values (that I know exist), that doesn't return the expected values.

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (salary >= 1000 AND state = "AL", "MI","MA")
```

I can use a hash instead, except I am not sure how to get all my conditions in the query in that regard. That, I can do the following:

```
User.where(state: ["AL", "MI", "MA"])
```

And that works, but not sure how to have the salary >= condition in there as well.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd prefer to use Mark's solution, but to make your initial attempt work, you have to change `state = ?` to `state IN (?)`, like this:

```
User.where("state IN (?) AND salary >= ?", ["AL", "MI", "MA"], 1000)
```

This will generate a `WHERE ... IN ('...', '...')` query, which is what you need when passing an array.

The advantage of using a hash is that Rails automatically generates the correct SQL. It does matter if you pass a string or an array.

Comment: Thanks Mischa. The main reason I accepted your solution, even though Marks answer worked perfectly (and like you said, using a hash has its own advantages, as well as making it more readable), is that I am generating the query dynamically, so by having them all in the same string makes that generation easier.

Answer (score 4):

Simply chain the `where` clauses:

```
User.where(state: ["AL", "MI", "MA"]).where("salary >= ?", 1000)
```